# OnSaveInstanceState with Singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have a Singleton Data class, which I use to store data. I'm accessing it in different `Fragment`s.

When the first `Fragment` is loaded, it's no problem that all fields in the Singleton are `null`. When the second `Fragment` is shown, it depends on these fields to show its data. The first `Fragment` ensures these fields are initialized.

However, when the user presses the home button in the second `Fragment`, and opens it again after like an hour or so, the Singleton has lost all its data, and the `Fragment` tries to access `null` fields.

I wanted to implement the `onSaveInstanceState` method, but I'm stumped on how this works - I have no instance of the data to assign it to.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("DATA", Data.getInstance());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.getSerializable("DATA"); //What to do with this?
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: But, I am not sure I understand why the singleton would lose all it's data? The application is still running in the background, is it not? I use the same paradigm in my application and have not seen this data loss.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem, so I guess it does.

Comment: Interesting! If you have any idea on what causes the data in the singleton to disappear, please post. This is causing me concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the fragments both hosted in the same Activity? If so, why not store the shared state in a member of the Activity, and use the Activity's onSaveInstanceState() and onCreate() to save and restore it. In your fragments you can then do...

```
((MyActivityClass)getActivity()).getSharedState()
```

Otherwise, you could make your singleton object manage a member object that can be serialized and deserialized:

```
MySingleton.instance().saveTo(outState);
MySingleton.instance().restoreFrom(savedInstanceState);
MySingleton.instance().getState();
```

Where

```
public void restoreFrom(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mState = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("DATA");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look a [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject). *onSaveInstanceState* method it's not very advisable if you need to carry large objects.